# Sbt: is it possible to import a file outside the project in build.sbt?

Tags: sbt

Context:

I have several applications and each has its own build.sbt.

Those applications depend on an other app with

```
lazy val sharedApp = RootProject(file("../shared-app"))
```

The problem is that I have to repeat on every build.sbt the configuration of the shared app and it is cumbersome.

How could I do in order to do that?
Is there a way to import a file that I would place in this shared app? (and so in the parent folder of the build.sbt file)

Comment: you could extract it to the some scala file, that you could import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Scala code in the build "project", to do whatever you want and it could be the case if you store parent project config there.

I see it something like this:

**Parent.scala**

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  // Versions
  lazy val someVersion = "2.3.8" 


  // Libraries
  val someLib = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
  val someLib2 = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion

}
```

and later in your **build.sbt** you could import it and it could reduce your cumbersome code, e.g.

**build.sbt**

```
import Parent._

// user keys from Parent.scala to quicker setup your parent project
```

Make any sense for your use-case?

Some reference materials - [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Organizing-Build.html)